# Is there a method to control and prevent deformations while you are creating a rig?

Tags: mesh, rigging

This question could be too wide but, Is there a method to control and prevent deformations while you are creating a rig? In other words after assigning each bone to one or more vertex groups, can i control the strenght and the relation between them (the bone and the vertex groups) with specific tools in blender?

P.S. except weight painting

I was rigging an human character and i have just ended the armature. I thought i have done a good job but when i started to animate the mesh here the deformations come.

[image]

I'll focus on 4 points where i can't control the mesh:

[image]

and this one (in particular there 2 points are the hell for me)

[image]

I can't control the deformations that happend while i'm trying to animate. Many people tell me to use weight painting but i think it isn't enought to resolve the problem. That's why i asked this question: there is a method to control deformations? I saw videos where they don't use automathic weight but empty groups

[image]

and assign vertex groups to the bone manually. I tried it but it's too complex for a rig like that or simply i'm too lazy. I can't find a real exit from this situation.

I add a picture of a deformation

[image]

Comment: Please explain why you want to do this.  What problem are you trying to solve? Motivation might help us to understand. [prevent deformations] of what? [assigning each bone to one or more vertex groups] means what? The bones and vertex groups are matched by name.  The issues of the question need to be made clearer.   Please include an image.

Comment: I edit the question. If you can help me it would be great!